# How to add bracket formatting when typing in typing in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, brackets

when writing in visual studio code my brackets used to automatically format as

```java
function(){
   //cursor here 
}
```

however now it automaticly formats as

```java
function(){
//cursor here}
```

I have cruised through stack overflow and user settings in vs code but failed to find anything of use.

Specifically in java

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, type and select **Java:Open Java Formatter Settings**

   [image]
2. Modify the following in the open file

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_annotation_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_array_initializer" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block_in_case" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_constructor_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_constant" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_lambda_body" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_method_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_switch" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
```

change into

```xml
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_annotation_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_array_initializer" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block_in_case" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_block" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_constructor_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_constant" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_enum_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_lambda_body" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_method_declaration" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_switch" value="next_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_type_declaration" value="next_line"/>
```

3. After the modification is completed, open the settings and find the **java.format.settings.url** setting item. Enter the path of the file you just modified

   [image]
4. restart VS Code

Comment: Hey ! I followed the instructions you gave and it didnt seem to help! (I had to create a new eclipse-formatter.xml in the root directory of my project)
this problem is persistent throughout my whole vs code eg: I have the same problem writing in typescript.

Comment: Try adding a configuration to disable automatic formatting in **settings.json**. `"java.format.onType.enabled": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.formatOnType": false,`

Comment: Hi there!, this didnt work for me. however I reset my vs code settings and the problem is now fixed, I must have had some other setting overriding it... thanks for your help !!